# Element-wise string comparison

Tags: python, string, comparison, element

I need a fast function for element-wise comparison of two strings. Example:

```
text1 = 'absabeadg'
text2 = 'abSatyaxguz'
diff = compare(text1,text2) # should return diff=[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far?  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why does it need to be fast? Even the slowest way I can think of to do this will still handle strings of that size so quickly that you'll never notice the time.

Answer (score 14):

Zero effort shown, but what the heck, it's the weekend:

```
>>> text1 = 'absabeadg'
>>> text2 = 'abSatyaxguz'
>>> 
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> 
>>> [int(c0==c1) for c0, c1 in izip_longest(text1, text2)]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

This uses [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to combine (potentially) different-length sequences together, and the fact that `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`.

[Update:]

Since there seems to be some dispute about whether this output makes much sense, here's a different approach which gives the same answer:

```
>>> [int(text1[i:i+1] == text2[i:i+1]) for i in range(max(len(text1), len(text2)))]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

(The debate, as near as I can tell, seems to be about whether it makes sense to return `0` when comparing nothing to something.  I think it's perfectly reasonable, and is how string slices behave -- we can compare the empty string to a nonempty string and always get `False == 0`.)

Answer (score 3):

For no-import-modules-readable-solution I guess you can just use this one:)

```
text1 = "absabeadg"
text2 = "abSatyaxguz"
len1 = len(text1)
len2 = len(text2)
result = []
for index in range(min(len1, len2)):
    result.append(int(text1[index] == text2[index]))
result.extend([0]*abs(len1-len2))
print result
```

For list comprehension fun:

```
text2 = "absabeadg"
text1 = "abSatyaxguz"
len1 = len(text1)
len2 = len(text2)

print [int(text1[i] == text2[i]) for i in range(min(len1, len2))] + [0]*abs(len1-len2)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer if `text1` is longer than `text2`. Maybe `[0 if len1 < len2 else 1]*abs(len1-len2)`? Also, I'm betting a list comprehension will be faster than a manual `append` loop, and the OP did explicitly ask for "a fast function".

Comment: Hi mate, can you please give me example of this none-working case? :)
And would append list comprehension solution, just for fun.

Comment: Try it on `aa`, `b` and it'll give you `[0, 0]` instead of `[0, 1]`. (Of course the OP didn't strictly define the logic, or give us lots of sample tests, but it seems most likely that, as all of the other answers assume, he wants `''` to sort before any actual character, since that's the usual way things are done.

Comment: And for a list comprehension: You can directly transform any `result = []; for foo in bar: result.append(baz(foo))` into `result = [baz(foo) for foo in bar]`. So, in your case: `result = [int(text1[index] == text2[index]) for index in range(min(len1, len2))]`.

Comment: As you can see, I added a list comprehensive solution.
About the logic - what I've understood from the user is that the results should be like that. I would love to hear about what actual logic he wants.

Comment: The standard rule for lexicographical comparison is that the "missing characters" at the end of the shorter sequence compare less. `"abcd" > "abc"` in every computer language ever invented, and the phone book, and the natural answer any school child will give you, so assuming that the OP intended the opposite just because he didn't explicitly say he wants the same thing everyone always wants is a bit perverse.

Comment: @abarnert: I don't quite follow your argument here.  My sol'n returns `[0, 0]` as well, and not for any reason involving sorting.

Comment: @DSM: I didn't mention sorting at all, but really, the difference between sorting two characters and comparing two characters is just what you return. Anyway, the whole point of this question is comparisons. If you return numbers for no reason involving comparisons, you're not returning the right numbers.

Comment: @abarnert: okay, I'm really confused now about what you're saying, but then I'm a bear of very little brain.  I thought you were using "lexicographical comparison" -- a sorting rule -- to explain why you thought the OP "wants '' to sort before any actual character" -- which also mentions sorting -- to explain why it should should return `[0, 1]` instead of `[0, 0]` for `aa, b`.  I'm a little disappointed in myself: usually I can make sense of what someone else is saying even if I don't agree, but here I'm completely lost.

Comment: @DSM: Sorry, I think I was mislead by one of the other answers. The OP wants to do an element-wise `==`, not an element-wise `<=`. In that case, you're right, it's perfectly reasonable to treat nothing as `!=` anything. (It would not be reasonable to treat nothing as '<' if it appears in `s1`, `>` if it appears in `s2`… but since `!=` is symmetrical, that's irrelevant.) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DSM: Although now that I look at the OP's test case, there is no example where `s2[i] > s1[i]`—it's always either `==` or `<`. And all he says is "compare". So the problem isn't very well-specified… not surprising, given that it's voted -6 and the OP never answered anyone's questions or comments. But I think the `==` interpretation is the most obvious one. So again, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

you could use numpy/pylab:

```
import pylab as p

a = p.fromstring("asdfg", dtype=p.int8)
b = p.fromstring("aqwer", dtype=p.int8)

print a == b
```

You'd have to pad the result yourself if the strings are of different length, and optionally convert the array of boolean values to a list of integers, if that is required.

Comment: +1. For large-enough strings, this will probably be the fastest solution without writing your own C (or at least Cython) code. (And for small strings, who cares?) And can do both missing steps automatically pretty easily. See http://pastebin.com/dDu7S4Vp for an example. (Obviously appending `count` NULs instead of `count-len(text)` is a bit wasteful, but unless the strings are huge that won't make much difference, and it's a little simpler this way. Also, I used just plain `numpy` because I don't have `pylab` on this machine.)